# how to install teleport (for SSH)?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, snap

Looking to install [teleport](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport) in order to `SSH` into a server which is [behind a firewall and to traverse NAT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423166/17056).

Build this from source, as described at github, or might it be available elsewhere?  I don't see a PPA, but perhaps I missed it.

(To `SSH` to a server behind NAT and firewall.)

Comment: I see some binaries available which might be an easier option? Link here: https://gravitational.com/teleport/docs/2.4/quickstart/#installing-and-starting

Comment: Looks like you have to build it from source. Its also a bit difficult to search for it, since there seems to be another package with the same name...